# Can I remove a line in ListPlot and put ticks on the right

Tags: plotting

Why does my `ListPlot` have a gray line at $x=0$? I have set `Ticks` and `PlotRange` options.

[image]

```
traj = ListPlot[data[[All, -1, 1 ;; 2]], 
  Ticks -> {Range[-7, 2, 1], Range[0, 7, 1]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 2}, {0, 6.4}}, AxesOrigin -> {2, 0}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

The `data[[All, -1, 1;;2]]` is

```
{{0, 0}, {-0.0207813, 0.019339}, {-0.0423047, 0.0379762}, {-0.0645281,
   0.0558731}, {-0.0874069, 0.0729935}, {-0.110893, 
  0.0893037}, {-0.134937, 0.104773}, {-0.159486, 
  0.119373}, {-0.184484, 0.133079}, {-0.209874, 0.145869}, {-0.235596,
   0.157725}, {-0.261588, 0.168632}, {-0.287786, 0.17858}, {-0.314125,
   0.187561}, {-0.340538, 0.195572}, {-0.366957, 
  0.202614}, {-0.393312, 0.208694}, {-0.419535, 0.21382}, {-0.445554, 
  0.218009}, {-0.471301, 0.221278}, {-0.496706, 0.223652}, {-0.5217, 
  0.225159}, {-0.546215, 0.225832}, {-0.570185, 0.225709}, {-0.593547,
   0.224831}, {-0.616238, 0.223244}, {-0.6382, 0.221}, {-0.659377, 
  0.218151}, {-0.679716, 0.214756}, {-0.699169, 0.210876}, {-0.717693,
   0.206575}, {-0.735246, 0.201918}, {-0.751796, 
  0.196977}, {-0.767311, 0.19182}, {-0.781768, 0.186521}, {-0.795147, 
  0.181153}, {-0.807435, 0.17579}, {-0.818623, 0.170506}, {-0.82871, 
  0.165375}, {-0.837699, 0.160471}, {-0.845598, 0.155864}, {-0.852423,
   0.151627}, {-0.858194, 0.147827}, {-0.862934, 
  0.144531}, {-0.866675, 0.141804}, {-0.869452, 0.139705}, {-0.871303,
   0.138293}, {-0.872274, 0.137622}, {-0.872411, 
  0.137742}, {-0.871767, 0.1387}, {-0.870396, 0.140538}, {-0.868357, 
  0.143295}, {-0.86571, 0.147003}, {-0.86252, 0.151693}, {-0.85885, 
  0.157389}, {-0.854767, 0.16411}, {-0.850342, 0.171873}, {-0.845641, 
  0.180687}, {-0.840736, 0.19056}, {-0.835697, 0.201491}, {-0.830594, 
  0.21348}, {-0.825497, 0.226516}, {-0.820475, 0.240591}, {-0.815598, 
  0.255686}, {-0.810931, 0.271782}, {-0.80654, 0.288856}, {-0.802491, 
  0.30688}, {-0.798844, 0.325821}, {-0.795661, 0.345647}, {-0.792997, 
  0.366319}, {-0.790908, 0.387797}, {-0.789447, 0.410036}, {-0.788662,
   0.432991}, {-0.788599, 0.456613}, {-0.789302, 0.480852}, {-0.79081,
   0.505656}, {-0.79316, 0.530969}, {-0.796383, 0.556737}, {-0.80051, 
  0.582902}, {-0.805566, 0.609407}, {-0.811572, 0.636192}, {-0.818547,
   0.663198}, {-0.826505, 0.690364}, {-0.835456, 
  0.717632}, {-0.845408, 0.74494}, {-0.856364, 0.772227}, {-0.868322, 
  0.799435}, {-0.881279, 0.826504}, {-0.895226, 0.853375}, {-0.910151,
   0.879991}, {-0.926038, 0.906294}, {-0.942869, 
  0.932229}, {-0.960619, 0.957743}, {-0.979263, 0.982783}, {-0.998771,
   1.0073}, {-1.01911, 1.03124}, {-1.04024, 1.05456}, {-1.06212, 
  1.07721}, {-1.08472, 1.09917}, {-1.10798, 1.12037}, {-1.13185, 
  1.14079}, {-1.15629, 1.1604}, {-1.18123, 1.17917}, {-1.20663, 
  1.19706}, {-1.23241, 1.21406}, {-1.25853, 1.23014}, {-1.28491, 
  1.2453}, {-1.3115, 1.25951}, {-1.33822, 1.27277}, {-1.36501, 
  1.28508}, {-1.3918, 1.29644}, {-1.41852, 1.30685}, {-1.44511, 
  1.31633}, {-1.47148, 1.32487}, {-1.49758, 1.33251}, {-1.52334, 
  1.33927}, {-1.54869, 1.34517}, {-1.57356, 1.35024}, {-1.59789, 
  1.35451}, {-1.62162, 1.35803}, {-1.64469, 1.36084}, {-1.66705, 
  1.36298}, {-1.68864, 1.3645}, {-1.70941, 1.36546}, {-1.72931, 
  1.3659}, {-1.7483, 1.3659}, {-1.76635, 1.3655}, {-1.78342, 
  1.36476}, {-1.79948, 1.36376}}
```

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: The vertical line at `x=0` is due to the option `GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}` which is part of the collection of  options injected by `PlotTheme -> "Scientific"`. Try `ListPlot[data[[All, -1, 1 ;; 2]], PlotRange -> {{-6, 2}, {0, 6.4}}, GridLines -> None, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {All, None}}]`?